# Adding Timestamp to Exported Filename in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am exporting to a CSV using a job with xp_cmdshell. I need the filename to include a timestamp. The code I currently have is...

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM dbo.tablename" queryout "C:\filename-timestamp.csv" -T -c -t, '
```

As you can see, I need the 'timestamp' to be replaced with the actual timestamp, and for the format to be .csv, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

This gives date and time both and make it windows compatible filename as well

```
DECLARE @dt AS VARCHAR(30)
SELECT @dt = REPLACE( CONVERT(VARCHAR(26),getdate(),120),':','-')
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM dbo.tablename" queryout "C:\filename-' + @dt +'" -T -c -t, '
```

Answer (score 2):

try the following:

```
declare @timestamp datetime = getdate()
declare @cmd varchar(200)
set @cmd='bcp "SELECT * FROM dbo.tablename" queryout "C:\filename-'+cast(@timestamp as varchar(50))+'" -T -c -t, '
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd
```